# Scrapy suppress handled errors

Tags: python, error-handling, scrapy, twisted

**Relevant Code**

```
def start_requests( self ):
    requests = [ Request( url['url'], meta=url['meta'], callback=self.parse, errback=self.handle_error ) for url in self.start_urls if valid_url( url['url'] )]
    return requests

def handle_error( self, err ):
    # Errors being saved in DB
    # So I don't want them displayed in the logs
```

I've got my own code for saving error codes in DB. I don't want them displayed in the log output. How can I suppress these errors?

Note that I don't want to suppress all errors - just the ones being handled here.

Comment: Do you mean changing the logging level?

Comment: No, I would simply like to not display the errors I'm receiving in the `handle_error` method

Comment: It could be that these errors are logged even before your error handler is called.

Comment: can you share log examples of the errors?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `self.skipped.add`, `self.failed.add` with `isinstance` condition in your `handle_error` method.

[Here is an example](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/tests/test_spidermiddleware_httperror.py#L37)

```
def on_error(self, failure):
    if isinstance(failure.value, HttpError):
        response = failure.value.response
        if response.status in self.bypass_status_codes:
            self.skipped.add(response.url[-3:])
            return self.parse(response)

    # it assumes there is a response attached to failure
    self.failed.add(failure.value.response.url[-3:])
    return failure
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer by @Daniil Mashkin seems to be the most comprehensive solution.

For simple cases, you can add http error codes `Spider.handle_httpstatus_list` or `HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES` in `Settings.py`.

This will send some erroneous answers to your callback function, thus skipping logging as well

Answer (score -1):

Use a simple try-except in your function. As long as you handle the exception by yourself (adding rows to the db, just "pass", ...), twisted won't recognize the error.
e.g.

```
def handle_error( self, err ):
    try:
        #do something that raises an exception
        #twisted won't log this as long as you handle it yourself
        myvar = 14 / 0
    except:
        pass
```